# Connect to remote Docker via Node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, docker

I have Docker set up and running on one of my servers and can connect to it remotely like this:

`docker --tlsverify -H tcp://web2.webcom.dk:4243 images`

I used [this](http://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-raring-1304-and-saucy-1310-64-bit) and [this](http://sheerun.net/2014/05/17/remote-access-to-docker-with-tls/) to get it set up.

What I would like to do is to be able to connect to it via Node.js and have tried doing so with [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) which to me seems to be the best option.

Here's my code:

```
Docker = require 'dockerode'

docker = new Docker
  host: 'tcp://web2.webcom.dk'
  port: 4243
  tls: true
  tlscacert: '/Users/jacob/.docker/ca.pem'
  tlscert: '/Users/jacob/.docker/cert.pem'
  tlskey: '/Users/jacob/.docker/key.pem'
  tlsverify: true

container = docker.getContainer '826544226fdc'
container.start (err, data) ->
  return console.error err if err?
  console.log data
```

That doesn't work though, as I get this error:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

This works locally:

```
Docker = require 'dockerode'

docker = new Docker
  host: '192.168.59.103'
  port: 2375
  socketPath: false

docker.run 'ubuntu', ['bash', '-c', 'uname -a'], process.stdout, (err, data, container) ->
  return console.error err if err?
```

But if I use my remote hosts IP and port I get this:

```
{ [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 0, code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT' }
```

How can I connect to my remote host?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning, for those not immediately recognizing it, that the code is [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a `HTTP PARSER ERROR`, because your dockerd speeks HTTPS and you are using HTTP to connecting it.
If you use tls, you must set the prococol field to `https`. here is my config:

```
docker: {
  host: '192.168.59.103'
  port: 2376
  protocol: 'https'
  ca: fs.readFileSync(process.env.DOCKER_CERT_PATH + '/ca.pem')
  cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.DOCKER_CERT_PATH + '/cert.pem')
  key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.DOCKER_CERT_PATH + '/key.pem')
}
```

Comment: correct, I even answered that myself for someone else: https://github.com/apocas/dockerode/issues/100#issuecomment-59598714 good loop